# Определения типа данных

Tags: php

В БД в поле text храню некие данные: просто текст, serialize-данные, JSON. Как можно определить тип данных, чтобы применить нужную функцию?

Comment: Вообще не есть хорошо делать из БД свалку не пойми чего, но коли уж так и совсем ничего нельзя сделать, я бы добавил поле, где будет указано какой тип данных хранится в нужной ячейке. Ну а там уже просто всё)

Comment: Соглашусь с @Виталий Кустов

Comment: оно, так...просто таблица - это настройки системы... и настройки могут быть в виде массива, или просто текст...

ограничился двумя типами: text, serialize-данные... без JSON. Но вот написать бы регулярку для serialize-данных...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое простое решение:

```
if($a = json_decode($text, true))
    return $a;
elseif($a = unserialize($text))
    return $a;
else
    return $text;
```

Но есть один минус: тратится время на декодирование, если строка не подпадает под проверяемый формат.
С интересом буду ждать решение через регулярки. =)

Comment: интересный подход... через регулярку... но... в регулярке не силен))

Впринцыпе, ресурс не сильно нагруженный, поэтому думаю и так сойдет:

    if(!is_numeric($text)){
        if($a=unserialize($text)){
               //do something with $a;
        }else{
               //do something with $text;
        }
    }else{
         //do something with $text;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
gettype();
```

получишь тип переменной.

Comment: "string", по-любому. =)

Comment: та в php все string...

А мое самое любимое это то что проверка вида 

    is_numeric(1) // false xD это же boolean!11!!АДИН

Comment: тип поля текстовое и туда пихается либо простой текст, либо цыфра, либо serialize-рованный текст... с цыфрами и текстом просто...а сериалайз...

Comment: var_dump(is_numeric(1));
    var_dump(is_numeric('1'));

Оба в true.

Comment: Действительно...

Возможно ( скорее всего ) это была не `is_numeric` а `is_int`, проверил результат:

    is_int(1); // все нормально - true
    is_int('1'); // false

Comment: а как насчет такой записи "1е4"?))))) это число...